# Mobile Browser Simulators for Desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile, simulator

Can anyone recommend any Mobile Browser Simulators like Opera Mini? http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/ Is there any Chrome or Safari simulator? I found a similar question in the archives but it's 3 years old so I'm guessing there has been some new additions since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode comes with the iOS Simulator.

It can be found in:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications`

As for an Android simulator (Chrome is *not* the browser Android handsets use -- they just released a version, but it's not the default and it only runs on Ice Cream Sandwich), you should install the [Android developer tools](http://developer.android.com) and set up a new test Android device.

You'll have the browser app in there.

All of this being said, testing on a desktop for mobile devices, even in a simulator/emulator, is a horrible replacement for actual-device testing.  We don't even bother doing anything other than quick acid-tests on the desktop stuff -- it's just not a good replacement at all.

Comment: Cheers for the link and totally agree that testing on a desktop for mobile devices is a horrible replacement for actual device testing but it's not always feasible (as in my case) to test on all devices natively as I only have access to iPhone and Android devices so I guess I'm looking for the closest alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, [Chrome Developer Tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) allows faking the User Agent and emulation (dispatching) of touch events with mouse events (Chrome 19, dev channel at the moment). Device screen resolution emulation is under development.

Answer (score 2):

Most web based mobile browser emulators fail to capture the nuances of specific mobile browsers & devices. I would recommend using [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/) or [Device Anywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/index.aspx). You can test in a full range of real mobile browsers from the comfort of your desktop.